# Keeping processes alive when closing SSH connection on MobaXTerm

Tags: linux, ssh, process, gnu-screen, nohup

I'm facing somme issue when trying to keep process alive when shutting down session in MobaXTerm.
I have a java process which should run on a linux server.

I am using two commands, `nohup` and `screen`.

For nohup, i am using the following command >  `nohup ./JRE/bin/java -jar ./core.jar start -wgm > logfile.log 2>&1 &`
When using screen, i juste use `screen`, run `./JRE/bin/java -jar ./core.jar start -wgm` and then detach the screen using `Ctrl`+`a`+`d`.

What my problem is, is when i'm trying these commands with PuTTY, i manage to keep the java process that i launch when i'm closing the PuTTY application and shutting down the session.

When using MobaXTerm, it just don't work. I'm closing the tab of my ssh connection and when i reconnect the java process is stopped.

Is there something i'm missing since i'm doing exactly the same method on the two applications and the beahvior is different ?

Thanks.

Comment: The behavior with PuTTY is the expected one. It seems that MobaXTerm is sending a KILL or other signal that it shouldn't. If you run `strace java ...`, you might capture some information about what's stopping Java.